# displaying first ten contact in one page and other in second page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pagination

I have requirement and I am not configuring out what to do for displaying first 10 contacts in the first page(table view), after 10th contact, it should display remaining 10 contact in second page(table view).

It should also display toolbar as soon 11th contact is added in table view showing the "Next" and "Previous" .

Please let me know from where I should start? 
Any tutorial or reference is appriciated

Comment: Are you sure that a tableview is the right approach? It's made to show lots of data and it's way easier to scroll down the next 50 contacts than with pagination. However, does your requirement come from an API that is used with pagination?

Comment: i dont think so tableview is right approach!! can u suggest me if any api exist regarding my problem so that i can use it in my application. what is pagination .. i don,t have any idea about it!!

Comment: oh!! i got it. yes nick, I want to paginate the uitable view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination is nothing else than going through pages, just like you described.

If you want to use pagination show only as many entries as will fit on the screen, so the user always sees everything and doesn't need to scroll. You could still use a tableView and disable the scrolling though I still think a tableView is a very good way to show large amounts of data.

To navigate through your data some of these three approaches may give you an idea:

**Buttons in a UIToolbar to go forth and back**

[image]

**UISegmentedControl in a UIToolbar**

[image]

**UIPageControl at the bottom, whole content is in a UIScrollView, user can swipe to go through pages**

[image]

Comment: ok!! i got it!! but how can i limit first 10 rows in a page and other ten on other page?

Comment: Say you've got a model as NSArray containing 100 entries, then you reference only 10 by using `subarrayWithRange:` and use that new array as datasource for your tableview.

Comment: @nick: i am new bee in iphone application development. i think u are not getting me!! what i am trying to say that, suppose if i have total of 50 rows and if rows exceed then 10 then the tableview should  stop scroll and segment controll or any other like toolbar should appear showing buttons 'privious and next'. any tutorial is appriciated.

Comment: how can i reload the same custom cell/ table view with all new entries from array when i vl click on next segment controll button!?? help mme with little bit code!!

Comment: Do you already have implemented a tableview and its datasource and delegate methods?

Comment: @nick: yes i have implemented.sorry for late reply!!