# pagination in a toolbar

Tags: ios, pagination

[With an image, Nick Weaver suggests a (first) example "Buttons in a UIToolbar to go forth and back" here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910834/) I would like sample code to produce the UIToolbar in that example. In my app I want to "page" through an array which contains up to 36 elements, but not to show the elements, only to show the element number in the toolbar and allow the user to control the element number with the previous and next buttons. [There is no UITextField or Keyboard involved, so I am not finding ready-made controls or code in SO.]

Comment: I have created a toolbar, but I don't know how to make the middle button just a label and not a button, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer tells how to put a UILabel inside a UIView in a UIToolbar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333441/adding-a-uilabel-to-a-uitoolbar/333509#333509)

[This tutorial shows how to put counter values into a UILabel.](http://www.geekylemon.com/WEBPROTECT-xcodetapcounter.htm)

Now I want to learn how to resize the UIView and UILabel inside the UIToolbar. Right now they are way too wide. I think the answer is using "Content Hugging..." and "Content Compressing..." features in StoryBoard.